# CodeMirror force next line from 80 position

Tags: javascript, editor, codemirror

Is there a way that I can force line break when user tries to type any character after column 80 for a document in code mirror.

Also optionally for indent on the next line

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do that. On cursor activity, test if current character index is 80 or over. if so, replace selection with new line "\n" . 
but do you really want to do that? break a word in half?

```
  editor.on("cursorActivity" ,function(editor){
   currentChar = editor.getCursor().ch    
   if (currentChar >= 80){
   editor.replaceSelection("\n" ,"end")
   }
   })
```

Comment: Thank you it does lead to what I am looking for.. Just that behavior is little weird.. Actually I would like user to be not able to type after 80 char not really break new line... but I though new line break may be easier to achieve.